# The projection of $v_1-v_2$

Tags: vector-spaces

> Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be two orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ in respect with standard dot product and $U=span\{v_1,v_2\}$. Prove that the projection of $v_1 - v_2$ onto $U$ is $v_1 - v_2$.I know that $\text{Proj}_U(v_1-v_2) = \frac{<v_1,  v_1-v_2>}{ \|v_1^2\|} v_1 + \frac{<v_2 , v_1-v_2>}{\|v_2^2\|} v_2 $.In this point I am stuck because I can't prove what I have asked .

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please note that questions showing no effort tend to be voted down and will be closed. You should edit the question to show your work

Answer (score 0):

If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal, then the projection of a vector $w$ onto $U=\text{span}\{v_1, v_2\}$ is

$$\text{Proj}_U(w) = \frac{v_1 \cdot w}{v_1 \cdot v_1} v_1 + \frac{v_2 \cdot w}{v_2 \cdot v_2} v_2.$$
(Check your notes for something to this effect.)

You can then check that if $w$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, then $\text{Proj}_U(w)=w$ by plugging it into the above formlua.